# how to do partial fraction decomposition on this equation

Tags: partial-fractions

I have a fractional function  $\frac{1}{x(1+x^{n-1})}$. using PFD: $\frac{A}{(1+x^{n-1})}+ \frac{B}{x}$, that means $Ax+(1+x^{n-1})B=1$.

For this to hold, we need $A=0, B=0, B=1$, which is of course impossible.

**Does that mean that this fraction cannot be decomposed? I remember reading that all fractions of polynomials can be decomposed.**

Comment: Well you need instead of $B$ to have a polynomial with degree $x^{n-2}$ or to simplify $1+x^{n-1}$

Comment: Do you mean $A$ instead of $B$? setting $A=-x^{n-2}$ gives $\frac{-x^{n-2}}{1+ x^{n-1}}$. I'm not sure how to integrate that.

Comment: Think of it like this what is the derivative of $x^{n-1}$?

Answer (score 1):

A and B can be polynomials.

In this case,
$A=-x^{n-2},B=1$
Works.

Comment: Of course, I didn't realize that. That gives $\frac{-x^{n-2}}{1+ x^{n-1}}$. I'm not sure how to integrate that, though?